# issue getting result in search bar in swift

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

[image][image]   i am working on a searchbar.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = patientArray.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

In this above 2 images, If i am writting the exact same string, then i am getting the result . But if i am searching for any numbers like "20". then the result is empty.
How to fix the issue that if i search for any containing text(it may be numbers or text), i will get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching from the beginning of the string (`prefix`). If you want to search if a string contains a substring you have to use `contains`.

But there is a more efficient API, `range(of:options:)` which also avoids the repetitively calling of `lowercased()`

```
filteredData = patientArray.filter{$0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
```